# ESP32 - SPI "spi_bus_initialize: host already in use" with SDCARD

Tags: c++, esp32

I am trying to write to a sd card using an esp32. The problem is that I cannot mount the unit. The SPI bus does not seem to work. I am using VSPI, since using HSPI it restarts constantly, it seems to be due to the use of pin 12

My code is:

```
    esp_err_t ret;

    esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount_config_t mount_config = {
        .format_if_mount_failed = format,
        .max_files = 5,
        .allocation_unit_size = 16 * 1024
    };

    const char mount_point[] = MOUNT_POINT;
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Initializing SD card");


    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Using SPI peripheral");

    //spi_host_device_t host = SDSPI_HOST_DEFAULT(); //Usa HSPI (SPI2) o VSPI (SPI3) host.
    sdmmc_host_t host = SDSPI_HOST_DEFAULT();
    host.slot = VSPI_HOST;
    
    spi_bus_config_t bus_cfg = {
        .mosi_io_num = PIN_NUM_MOSI,
        .miso_io_num = PIN_NUM_MISO,
        .sclk_io_num = PIN_NUM_CLK,
        .quadwp_io_num = -1,
        .quadhd_io_num = -1,
        .max_transfer_sz = 4000,
    };

    //ret = spi_bus_initialize((spi_host_device_t)host.slot, &bus_cfg, 0);
    ret = spi_bus_initialize(VSPI_HOST, &bus_cfg, 2);
    
    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to initialize bus.");
        card = NULL;
        return;
    } 

    // This initializes the slot without card detect (CD) and write protect (WP) signals.
    // Modify slot_config.gpio_cd and slot_config.gpio_wp if your board has these signals.
    sdspi_slot_config_t slot_config = SDSPI_SLOT_CONFIG_DEFAULT(); // SDSPI_DEVICE_CONFIG_DEFAULT();

    slot_config.gpio_cs = (gpio_num_t)cs_pin;
    //slot_config.host_id = host.slot;

    //ret = esp_vfs_fat_sdspi_mount(mount_point, &host, &slot_config, &mount_config, &card);
    ret = esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount(mount_point, &host, &slot_config, &mount_config, &card);

    if (ret != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Failed to mount card.");
        card = NULL;
        return;
    }
```

Also use esp_vfs_fat_sdmmc_mount instead of esp_vfs_fat_sdspi_mount because the esp_vfs_fat_sdspi_mount function does not exist. why?

Pin used:
CS: 5
SCLK: 18
MISO: 19
MOSI: 23

Use platformio with Visual Studio Code.

This is my output console:

```
(320) sdcard: Initializing SD card␛[0m
␛[0;32mI (321) sdcard: Using SPI peripheral␛[0m
␛[0;31mE (321) spi: SPI3 already claimed by spi master.␛[0m
␛[0;31mE (323) spi_master: spi_bus_initialize(232): host already in use␛[0m
␛[0;31mE (330) sdcard: Failed to mount card.␛[0m
```